# Talking to UITableViewCell and UITableView from ViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios5

I have set up a table view with a custom cell in my storyboard view controller, and want to control it from my ViewController class. I have set up ViewController to act as my delegate. When I run the app it just displays an empty list and doesn't call my one cell which has a label on it. I'd expect to see this label in the list. I've wired the datasource and delegate to ViewController in storyboard. My .h and .m files are as below, edited for simplicity.

When I run it I get `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'` So it looks like the delegation isn't working properly. What have I missed? Do I need to connect the cell to anything?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end



@implementation ViewController
...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReportItem"];
return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: @Srikar. This was researched as thoroughly as I could before posting. So why mark it down? Give us noobs a break.

Comment: why assume I marked it down? Didnt do it buddy... I just edited your question to make it read better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` is returning nil. This might mean that you haven't set the identifier for your custom cell in Interface Builder (should be 'StateCell'). You can find this setting in the Attributes inspector when you select the custom cell in IB.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks Robin. I had ReportItem in my method, and ReportCell in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StateCell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
     if (cell == nil){
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]
     }
   return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks aahsanali. it still doesn't work just allocs an empty cell now. Which shows that my original call is returning nil and not a cell. Why I have no idea?

Comment: Would you tell me how you have defined/made custom cell?

Comment: I've discovered the issue. It's just that stack will not let me answer for 8 hours after posting. It was a simple typo. I had typed @"ReportItem" whilst in storyboard I had labels the reuse cell as ReportCell! Doh